# Performing arithmetic on a void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I am trying to perform arithmetic on an address. I need to make sure that it is on a 4 byte word boundary. This requires me to get an unsigned integer representation of the pointer to perform some math on. I have done this:

```
//memStartAddr is of type void* (from an external API function)
data32 tempAddr = reinterpret_cast<data32>(memStartAddr);
//adjust pointer to the next word boundary if needed
tempAddr = wordAlign(tempAddr);
//memStartAddress is a class variable of type unsigned char*
memStartAddress = reinterpret_cast<data8*>(tempAddr);
//calculate bytes lost due to above adjustment
data32 delta = (tempAddr - reinterpret_cast<data32>(memStartAddress));
//Take advantage of integer arithmetic to ensure usable size is a multiple
//of 4 bytes. Remainders are lost. Shrinks usable size if necessary.
memSize = ((size - delta) / 4) * 4;
```

This all works in my tests, however, using reinterpret_cast is considered a forbidden practice. Is there another way to do this? Or is an exception to the rule warranted here?

Comment: I think this is a valid case to use `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: Who says `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden? Are you following somebody's coding convention?

Comment: If `reinterpret_cast` is forbidden, why did the ISO C++ people consider it a good idea and approved it to be added to the language, and why does every C++ compiler have to implement it to be conforming? That's a lot of wasted productivity on something which is forbidden, isn't it!

Comment: I agree, however, it is a rule in the coding guidelines I have to follow in the group I work for which is why I am seeking a readable, intuitive workaround. I believe it has to to with preventing less knowledgeable people from using it incorrectly as you can really muck things up if you are not careful.

Comment: @radensb: "Aligning a pointer to 4 byte boundaries" would be mucking up on a platform where 8 bytes is needed. The explicit intent of `reinterpret_cast` is that such dangerous things are **possible and visible**. In C, the equivalent is `*(type*)(&expr)`, and that's easy to overlook.

Comment: @MSalters no, a `reinterpret_cast` is not equivalent to that C code. The C code you give most likely is an aliasing violation resulting in undefined behaviour (certainly for this case). `reinterpret_cast` reinterprets the representation. (In this case equivalent C is just a straight cast to the target type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `memStartAddress = std::align(4, objSize, memStartAddr, objSize+3);`. The standard function is a bit more flexible than you need, so you need to tell it that you want at most a +3 change in address.

Answer (score 0):

a tricky approach might be to have pointer to initial address
then on the pointer perform + 1 --> this will automatically result in the next address according to the size in bytes of the variable type it's pointing to.
**Note**: make sure you perform the +1 on the pointer not on the address (int* initialAddress --> perform the operation on initialAddress not on *initialAddress)

then you can perform a subtraction between the two and you'll have the number of bytes.

Comment: I thouhght of this approach. The issue is that I have to preform some integer arithmatic to get the number Im looking for. For example:

return ((reinterpret_cast<unsigned>(memAddr) + 3) / 4) * 4. which will return the unsigned version of memAddr or the address of the next 4 byte boundary

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid division.
Try this:

```
unsigned int pointer_value = (unsigned int) pointer;
if ((pointer_value & 0x3U) == 0U)
{
    // Pointer is on 4 byte boundary.
}
```

Some compilers may only optimize division by 4 and multiplication by 4 when the optimization levels are set on high.  The embedded compiler I'm using will call the division function when dividing by 4 rather than right shifting, unless the optimization setting is cranked up to high.

Comment: This is interesting. I know that the old C style casting will not fly with the coding guidelines I have to follow, but the elimination of integer division is a nice touch!